# Android app: How to trigger a sound play when you click on a moving asset not a button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making my first app, following some tutorials about making a game.

I have got to a point where i want a sound to play if the user manages to click on a moving object (png).

If they manage click on it, i would like the sound to play. I have googled but everything is related to buttons not a asset.

Can someone please provide me with a resource i can follow to understand how to do this, or some sample code with comments so i can learn?

I have research about playing sounds, but i am unable to find the correct resource i need to help me with when an object is touched with a finger in the android app.

Answer (score 0):

try using the "event trigger" component. the event trigger's pointer click should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use `AudioSource`:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html